# How to reduce title bar size?

Tags: gnome

I need to reduce the size of the title bar on all Gnome applications on an Ubuntu 14.04 Gnome 3.10/3.14 installation. The recommendation of adding configuration to `~/.config/gtk-3.0/gtk.css` did not work.

Answer (score 0):

Faced a similar problem after switching from Ubuntu to Debian Jessie... A post in the Arch Linux Boards pointed me in the right direction. According to that, before Gnome switched to GTK theming with CSS in 3.16, there was a guide in the Arch Wiki to modify the file **/usr/share/themes/Adwaita/metacity-1/metacity-theme-3.xml** for modifying the titlebar height. This path only applies for the Adwaita theme, I suppose, but for different themes it can't be much different.

By examining the document and superficially googling for some of the settings inside, this is what I could figure out:

```
<distance name="title_vertical_pad" value="X"/>
```

is the setting that refers to the regular padding of the  title bar. This setting occurs several times. For my purposes, it was sufficient to reduce the value where it is enclosed by the tags `<frame_geometry name="normal" ... >` and `<frame_geometry name="max" ... >`, referring to the title bar of a window in normal and maximized state each.

Note that the icons of window buttons will shrink together with the title bar size and that a very low `title_vertical_pad` setting (around <7) will cause the icons to be rendered as rectangles. Subtly increasing

```
<constant name="D_icons_grow" value="0" />
```

can fix this.

The xml document contains a warning at `<frame_geometry name="max" ... >` concerning `title_vertical_pad` that "This needs to be 1 less then the title_vertical_pad on normal state or you'll have bigger buttons", but I could notice no such effect, quite the contrary, the buttons appeared more different when I followed that advice. "7" on both with a `D_icons_grow` of "2" is what I went with. Just play around a little bit with the values and check the effects by saving the file, pressing ALT + F2 and entering "r" to reload the shell, but consider backing up the original file before.